# how to know what are the lines covered in the code for a particular point of execution in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to know what are the lines of code covered in the java class for a particular point of execution in eclipse. For example,if button click event is fired then how to know what are the lines of code is being executed during this event. Any plugins in eclipse or any free software for this to track the code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the following page, it will instruct you through the process. The only thing you need to do is prepare a j-unit test for your code (for the method that gets called when pressing the button).

http://crunchify.com/what-is-the-best-code-coverage-plugin-you-should-use-in-eclipse-ide/